# render "Upgrade Poetry to be able to read the lock file or, alternatively, regenerate the lock file with the `poetry lock` command."

Tags: python, render, python-poetry

i try to deploy by render.com

but backend fail to deploy

render said `"The lock file is not compatible with the current version of Poetry. Upgrade Poetry to be able to read the lock file or, alternatively, regenerate the lock file with the` poetry lock `command."`

but i think my poetry version is matched with poetry.lock

poetry --version is 1.6.1
and poetry.lock file said
`# This file is automatically @generated by Poetry 1.6.1 and should not be changed by hand.`

and i also tried delete poetry lock file -> poetry lock -> poetry install

but it doesn't work...

i am student and so i can not find the way please help me..

Comment: I have a condition where I can't read images, please post the erro as text here.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "my render backend fail to deploy": how? What do you run to deploy the backend? What is meant by "render" here? A Python package? Rendering to create an image? Something else? There is quite some background missing here that we'd have to guess.

Comment: @9769953 sorry i edit it. i mean render.com

Comment: So you're deploying some app on render.com, and that fails?

Comment: @9769953 yes..I think the issue might be related to a prior change in the Python version, where I had previously changed the version and later reinstalled the latest one.

Comment: But how are you deploying to render.com? Do you push to a repository, or some other way?

Comment: @9769953 i push a repository!

Comment: So you're poetry setup, with the lock file, is on your side, where you build the project?

Comment: @9769953 i use django for my backend and I'm building the project on my local computer

Comment: And poetry to manage that Django project, correct? Poetry 1.6.1 on your local machine?

Comment: @9769953 yes!! correct!

Comment: What is your build command on render.com?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue you're experiencing is because render's default poetry version is quite old. Somewhere around poetry 1.3, backwards compatibility was broken and newer `poetry.lock` files can't be read by older versions of poetry.

Render does let you [specify your poetry version](https://render.com/docs/poetry-version)- you should set it to whatever version you're using to generate the poetry.lock.

Comment: Would it also be possible (and maybe better) if the build dependency in the pyproject.toml file included the correct Poetry version? Then `pip install .` should handle the Poetry version, making it easier / clearer to keep things in sync.

Comment: I agree it'd be better to take the pyproject.toml route since your project config is more self contained to your own codebase, but from their docs at this time doesn't seem possible.